# How to delete matched columns from json dict compare with list in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have one json list and one json dict and I want to remove the objects from dict which 'id' column matches with elements of list.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = {"data":[{"id":1,"name":"shubham"},{"id":8,"name":"rahul"}]
```

I want output like:

```
b = {"data":[{"id":8,"name":"rahul"}]
```

Comment: Yeah both should be removed. I mean all the elements which matches id of b with list a should be removed in dict.

Comment: Those aren't JSON - JSON is text. Those are actual lists and dictionaries in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = {"data":[{"id":1,"name":"shubham"},{"id":8,"name":"rahul"}]

items = b['data']

for id in a:
   for it in items:
      if it['id'] == id:
         items.remove(it)
b['data'] = items
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = {"data":[{"id":1,"name":"shubham"},{"id":8,"name":"rahul"}]}

s = set(a)
for i, item in enumerate(b['data']):
    if item['id'] in s:
        del b['data'][i]
```